# Installing ffmpeg, librosa nad pydub in Apache Spark container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, ffmpeg

I'm working on a Python spark streaming project, that needs to use pydub and librosa to process audio, this libraries require having installed ffmpeg library. I'm having trubles to build the spark containers with this libraries, I don't know how to solve this problem.

I use a docker-compose.yml to buil the images, define ports, etc of the spark master and workers.
docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  spark-master:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data
       - ./data:/data
       - ./src:/src
       - ./output:/output
    environment:
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=master
  spark-worker-a:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
      - "7000:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-a
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data
       - ./data:/data
       - ./src:/src
       - ./output:/output       
  spark-worker-b:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    ports:
      - "9092:8080"
      - "7001:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-b
    volumes:
        - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
        - ./data:/opt/spark-data
        - ./data:/data
        - ./src:/src
        - ./output:/output
```

In the same path of the docker-compose.yml is the Dockerfile I'm using to build the image:

```
# builder step used to download and configure spark environment
FROM openjdk:11.0.11-jre-slim-buster as builder

# Add Dependencies for PySpark
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl vim wget software-properties-common ssh net-tools ca-certificates python3 python3-pip python3-numpy python3-matplotlib python3-scipy python3-pandas python3-simpy

RUN update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/python" "python" "$(which python3)" 1

# Fix the value of PYTHONHASHSEED
# Note: this is needed when you use Python 3.3 or greater
ENV SPARK_VERSION=3.0.2 \
HADOOP_VERSION=3.2 \
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark \
PYTHONHASHSEED=1

# Download and uncompress spark from the apache archive
RUN wget --no-verbose -O apache-spark.tgz "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" \
&& mkdir -p /opt/spark \
&& tar -xf apache-spark.tgz -C /opt/spark --strip-components=1 \
&& rm apache-spark.tgz


# Apache spark environment
FROM builder as apache-spark

WORKDIR /opt/spark

ENV SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077 \
SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 \
SPARK_LOG_DIR=/opt/spark/logs \
SPARK_MASTER_LOG=/opt/spark/logs/spark-master.out \
SPARK_WORKER_LOG=/opt/spark/logs/spark-worker.out \
SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 \
SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7000 \
SPARK_MASTER="spark://spark-master:7077" \
SPARK_WORKLOAD="master"

EXPOSE 8080 7077 6066

RUN mkdir -p $SPARK_LOG_DIR && \
touch $SPARK_MASTER_LOG && \
touch $SPARK_WORKER_LOG && \
ln -sf /dev/stdout $SPARK_MASTER_LOG && \
ln -sf /dev/stdout $SPARK_WORKER_LOG

# Install ffmpeg lib
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils gcc libpq-dev libsndfile-dev

#RUN apt-get update \
#&& apt-get upgrade -y \
#&& apt-get install -y \
#&& apt-get -y install apt-utils gcc libpq-dev libsndfile-dev

# Install required python libs
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY start-spark.sh /

CMD ["/bin/bash", "https://net.cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/start-spark.sh"]
```

The start-spark.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
. "https://net.cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/opt/spark/bin/load-spark-env.sh"
# When the spark work_load is master run class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
if [ "$SPARK_WORKLOAD" == "master" ];
then

export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=`hostname`

cd /opt/spark/bin && ./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip $SPARK_MASTER_HOST --port $SPARK_MASTER_PORT --webui-port $SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT >> $SPARK_MASTER_LOG

elif [ "$SPARK_WORKLOAD" == "worker" ];
then
# When the spark work_load is worker run class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Worker
cd /opt/spark/bin && ./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port $SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT $SPARK_MASTER >> $SPARK_WORKER_LOG

elif [ "$SPARK_WORKLOAD" == "submit" ];
then
    echo "SPARK SUBMIT"
else
    echo "Undefined Workload Type $SPARK_WORKLOAD, must specify: master, worker, submit"
fi
```

When I execute: "docker-compose up" I have the next error message:

```
[+] Running 4/4
 - Network spark_container_default             Created                                                                                0.9s 
 - Container spark_container-spark-master-1    Created                                                                                0.3s 
 - Container spark_container-spark-worker-a-1  Created                                                                                0.4s 
 - Container spark_container-spark-worker-b-1  Created                                                                                0.4s 
Attaching to spark_container-spark-master-1, spark_container-spark-worker-a-1, spark_container-spark-worker-b-1
spark_container-spark-master-1    | /bin/bash: https://net.cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/start-spark.sh: No such file or directory     
spark_container-spark-master-1 exited with code 127
spark_container-spark-worker-a-1  | /bin/bash: https://net.cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/start-spark.sh: No such file or directory     
spark_container-spark-worker-b-1  | /bin/bash: https://net.cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/start-spark.sh: No such file or directory     
spark_container-spark-worker-a-1 exited with code 127
spark_container-spark-worker-b-1 exited with code 127
```